# Read file from /data folder (with chmod 744) in android

Tags: android, chmod, rooted-device, read-data, appsflyer-android-sdk

I have a rooted device and I added a file named `test.txt` to the root `/data` directory.
And then I changed its permission to 744 with following adb command:

```
adb shell su -c 'chmod 744 /data/test.txt'
```

After the command the permission changed to `-rwxr--r--`

Now I want to read that file with this code:

```kotlin
                    val file = File("/data/test.txt")
                    val text = StringBuilder()
                    try {
                        val reader = BufferedReader(FileReader(file))
                        var line: String?
                        while (reader.readLine().also { line = it } != null) {
                            text.append(line)
                            text.append('\n')
                        }
                        reader.close()
                        showText(text.toString())
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        logE(e)
                    }
```

But it gives me this exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/test.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Now I know that some libraries can read files with 744 permission like AppsFlyer:
[AppsFlyer factory preinstall](https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/207032166-Pre-install-campaigns-for-Android-configuration-and-testing#system-properties-method-recommended)
As you see in documentation it mentions that:

> The manufacturer places the pre_install.appsflyer in a file path of its choosing. The pre_install.appsflyer file permissions should be set to 744.

So how can I read this data like AppsFlyer library?